# Calculation of the electrical resistance of an anisotropic conductor with spacially varying current density

Tags: electrical-resistance, ferromagnetism

Fist time posting here, so I apologize in advance for the terrible editing .
I am trying to figure out a way to calculate the total resistance of a rectangular structure with known spatially dependent current distribution and resistivity. Is there an analytical formula in integral form that I can use to achieve this?

Perhaps, something along the lines of:

[image]

Would this work?

The structure in question is a rectangular ferromagnetic film with conductive strips on the top side -- shown in orange, which change the local current direction (this is part of my work on a micromagnetic model of an AMR sensor). There is a slight variation in the resistivity in different parts of the film's volume (~ 1 - 5%).
[image: A basic drawing of the film]

I've thought that maybe I can treat the conductor as a series of slices in the ZY plane. However, I'm not sure if this would be feasible, as the current direction changes even in a single given plane. Any tips are really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It's actually simpler to think in terms of conductance. In general, you need to solve for the electric potential using the conservation of current:
$$
\nabla\cdot(\sigma\nabla V) = 0
$$
with $\sigma = \rho^{-1}$ the spatially dependent conductivity. Since you're talking about anisotropic material, you can assume in general that $\rho$ is a symmetric tensor, that is doubly contracted with the two del operators in the equation. You need to apply Dirichlet boundary conditions at the conducting armatures and Neuman boundary conditions at the (assumed insulated or else you don't have a properly defined resistance) other boundaries. You can find the current by integrating:
$$
j = -\sigma\nabla V
$$
on an armature (they are opposite from conservation of current). This will directly give you conductance as this expresses the current as a function of the imposed voltage integrated in the Dirichlet boundary conditions.

It's a bit strange that you already have the current density. Normally you want to know the total resistance only given the resistivity disribution. If you already have the current density from outside information, then you can just integrate the electric field:
$$
E = \rho j
$$
to get the voltage of the armatures. Note that the result should be path independent, so it is a good sanity check whether your parachuted current density is correct.

In general, the total resistance $R$ is a complicated functional of $\rho$, and there is no simple universal formula. For a complicated geometry as yours, you'll have to solve it numerically.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you please elaborate what Dirichlet boundary conditions should be applied?

Comment: You just impose the prescribed voltage. In your case $V_1$ for the left $x$ face and $V_2$ for the right $x$ face. Since you're interested in conductance, might as well normalise everything so that $V_1=0$ and $V_2=1$ so that the calculated current directly gives conductance.